# Ao Invés de mostrar texto linha por linha mostrar o texto inteiro

Tags: c#

Ao Invés de mostrar texto linha por linha mostrar o texto inteiro. Visual Studio Community 2017.

```
Stream entrada = File.Open(varexe + "\\Score.txt", FileMode.Open);
StreamReader leitor = new StreamReader(entrada);
string linha = leitor.ReadLine();
while (linha != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(linha);
    linha = leitor.ReadLine();
}
leitor.Close();
entrada.Close();
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Meio confuso. Mas se eu entendi bem, pq não concatenar em uma variavel no loop e mostra só no final?

Comment: @MalysterSnur conseguiu resolver o seu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o método `ReadToEnd()` e procure usar o using, quando estiver trabalhando com `Stream` e `File`, isso vai garantir o `Dispose()` do objeto assim que ele não estiver mais alocado

```
string texto = string.Empty;

using (Stream entrada = File.Open(varexe + "\\Score.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    StreamReader leitor = new StreamReader(entrada);
    texto = leitor.ReadToEnd();
}

MessageBox.Show(texto);
```